# Document Library Vs Asset Library

Tags: 2013, asset-library

Is there major difference between Document library and Asset Library in terms of functionality, Workflows, Document Sets or any other?

I got a task to create document sets which may hold `word`, `pdf`, `image`, `excel`, `ppt` files. It will have approval workflow on the documents. Also client want a thumbnail view for the same.

Since Asset library comes with Thumbnail view, I am planning to use it. Am I making the correct choice?

**Update:**

The library will have more images compare to office files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Asset Library is preconfigured to manage media content like images, audio and video files. It has extra features over document library like Thumbnail view, Automatic metadata extraction for image files.*

**Yes,** you can use it for sure to upload documents and use extra features that come with `asset library`. Also you can add workflow and other features like versioning and everything that's possible in document library. *Only thing you need to do is to add new content types for **Document** and **document set**.*

But remember that it's specially created to manage rich content (Media content).

Comment: Before going to use Asset Library just for thumbnail view, you can try **js link** to modify default document list view to make simple thumbnail view.

Comment: Hi Ashish, thanks for the reply, with respect to your last line, if i use Asset library will it add load on memory, database?

Comment: Hi, Not really, it will not make much difference in case of load on memory. But If you observed from on click of thumbnail view it redirect you to document display form, it will not open document directly. If you are okay with it, you can go for it.

Comment: With JSLink, how will you manage the thumbnails? If the library has 10 3 MB photos, the view with JSLink will literally ship 30 MBs of images down the pipe. Am I missing something with a normal Doc Lib?

Comment: Good Point, iOnline. I will have heavy images in that library. So jslink will give load on page load i assume